# Xamarin writing to External Storage (permissions)

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

First of all I would like to ask am I trying to write to correct path or not? I would like to have a log file on device and currently it is created and maintained this way:

```
  string documentsPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments);
  string filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "Log.txt");
```

I mean is this the right place or is it better to store it somewhere else? For example in internal storage?

Second question if above is fine and can be as it is, why following is doing nothing on app startup. I mean it does not request permissions for External Storage management?

```
  if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ManageExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted || 
    ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) != (int)Permission.Granted)
  {
    this.RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.ManageExternalStorage, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation }, 0);
  }
```

and following should be added in order to request External storage management permissions:

```
  if (!Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageManager)
  {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageAppAllFilesAccessPermission);
    Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromParts("package", this.PackageName, null);
    intent.SetData(uri);
    this.StartActivity(intent);
  }
```

Comment: Please tell which filePath all those functions finally deliver.

Comment: Short explanation: I want to write logs of application errors. So I have came up with solution to store this log file on external storage in documents path. However it looks like this path requires specific permissions, to be able to access log file read and write permissions in this particular path. Also it is not enough to just have read/write permissions but "manage external storage" permissions are needed.

Comment: ??? Why all this talking? I only asked for the path. You did not tell that. Please do. Tell the value of `filePath`.

Comment: What do you mean by value of `filePath`? It is `Path.Combine(documentsPath, "Log.txt");` and `documentsPath` is mentioned above. It is in the code so it is the same for all Android devices `"/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Log.txt"`

Comment: So the directory /storage/emulated/0/Documents is a good place to store files. You could also make your own subfolder there like /storage/emulated/0/Documents/MyFolder. You just need the normal WRITE permission. Not all files permission.